# Using pydev with Eclipse on OSX

Tags: python, eclipse

I setup PyDev with this path for the python interpreter
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Python
since the one under /usr/bin were alias and Eclipse won't select it. I can run my python script now but cannot run the shell as an external tool. The message I get is

variable references empty selection ${resource_loc}

Same if I use {container_loc}

Any thoughts ?

Sunit

Comment: I'd like to add an addendum to this question - the debugger for pydev runs really slowly if psyco is not enabled. Psyco only works on 32-bit machines, and MAC OS X is 64-bit.  I've read that you can set the interpreter to force 32-bit mode by specifying 'defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes' on the command line; however, this did not work for me.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I installed the Python.org version as well, this is a must.

I finally got PyDev working in Eclipse by pointing the interpreter to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
```

manually.  If you don't do it manually (by using the Autoconfig) it seems to not find the right version.

Answer (score 3):

Common practice seems to be to install an up-to-date Python 2.5 from python.org and use that instead of the system installation. I saw that recommended here and there when I got started on Mac OS X.

It installs under `/Library` (as opposed to `/System/Library`) so the system Python is intact. Pydev has /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python as its configured Python interpreter and all is well.

Can't state for sure that your trouble is due only to using the system's Python installation; in any case this way I have no trouble. Also, this way when you fiddle with your development environment (install things in site-packages, upgrade Python), anything that uses the system Python is sure to be unaffected.

Comment: I agree you should try the python.org version and not the system python.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a ancient post... but, in case of some newbee like me to get the better answer.

I just using "Eclipse Marketplace" from the "Help" menu and search for keyword "python" or "PyDev" to get PyDev, and get it successfully installed.

AND, you should add PyDev to the top-right dock.

For the instance, my eclipse on my laptop's OSX is (Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857).

Have fun, folks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `${resource_loc}` or `${container_loc}` (without any argument) are based on the current selection in your workbench when you are launching your script.

So are you selecting the right resource when selecting that script through the "external tool" runner ?
At least, click on the project name before you run one of the external programs.
Note: it works with a selection in the [Navigator or Package Explorers views](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg50264.html) (the latest might not be available in PyDev environment though)