# Launch and debug a single script in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am a beginner in using Eclipse and PyDev (Aptana Studio 3). I am not used to and i don't understand the workflow in such big IDEs as Eclipse.

I have a simple task: i have a simple Python script, which i want to open and run in Eclipse, having its output in Eclipse console. Or debug it.

Until now i used another IDE called [Eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), which allowed me to do what i want - open a file and run immediately, without creating a project or setting up launch configurations.

Is this possible in Eclipse, or i have to create a project for each file i want to run or debug? I want to understand how it works.

I guess i understand that creating a project is needed at least for settings up the paths (PYTHONPATH), but if it's a single script - somehow to use by default the current directory?

For example i have a folder called `snippets` where i keep a lot of python scripts which demonstrate some functionality. How do i open these files one by one and run them?

Most of my coworkers launch python scripts in a separate console - `python my_scipt.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have at least one project with the configuration you want (i.e.: syntax type, interpreter), then, open the file you want to run and press F9.

If it's an external file -- i.e.: a file that's not under a project in Eclipse -- it'll ask you to associate a project with the launch to get the needed information for the launch, but the file doesn't really have to be in the project (note that you can drag external files from your filesystem into Eclipse to open them).

I suggest you follow the steps on the getting started: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html (it guides you to configuring PyDev and explains how to do a run/debug session).

Comment: Just remembered a similar question I had answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194424/run-external-python-programs-with-eclipse-pydev/7203663#7203663