# eclipse: Run/Debug current file

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, aptana

In search of a **Python debugger** I stumbled upon **Aptana**, which is based on **eclipse**.

Often, I want to debug a single python script. However, Aptana won't let me run/debug the currently opened file directly.

Instead, it requires me to create a debug/run configuration for each file I would like to run/debug. Alternatively I could create a Python project in Aptana.

But: I don't want to. I just want to be able to run or debug the currently opened file. This way I would like to debug my scripts without being forced to create a project first (for each single script!).

Can it be that hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Aptana/Eclipse doesn't "realize" that the file you opened should be debugged using the Python debugger as it's not associated with a Python project/perspective (there's a lot of environment setup when a project is created in Aptana/Eclipse).

The simplest solution, IMO, would be to create a simple sandbox Python project and just stick your files in there to run/debug. Aptana should then realize you're dealing with Python and start running the Python debugger without setup (that's my experience w/ PyDev in Eclipse, at any rate).

Comment: A decent IDE should be able to recognize ".py" files as Python files and run/debug them right away. Yet your answer is correct, of course.

Comment: A case of trying to be everything to everyone while failing to be useful to anyone, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Run External Python Programs with Eclipse PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194424/run-external-python-programs-with-eclipse-pydev/7203663#7203663) (note: you really need a project, but your file doesn't need to be in it).