# Eclipse removing entries from the global easy_install.pth?

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev

We are having some annoying problems with Eclipse, which apparently have been always there, on Windows 7 + a custom python installation + Eclipse 3.7 and the latest Pydev.

The problem is basically that if when setting up the python interpreter you add all the libraries too, then Eclipse or Pydev or who knows what *deletes* all these entries from the global easy_install.pth file, which are also configured in Pydev.
This means that within Eclipse everything works fine, but anything outside of it can't possibly work correctly.

Now I find it hard to believe that noone noticed, so I would think that we're doing something wrong.

I also filled a bug which didn't get much attention yet:

https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3446052&group_id=85796&atid=577329

Any idea of what and why it could be?
Already being able to know exactly who and when modify that file would help a little bit, any suggested tool?

EDIT:
I'm trying with Process Monitor as suggested below.
So I fire up Eclipse, I run a simple Python command and I get something like this happened the file.

"File Time","Total Events","Opens","Closes","Reads","Writes","Read Bytes","Write Bytes","Get ACL","Set ACL","Other","Path"
"0.0000306","4","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","C:\python25\Lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth"

So basically it was open:1, closed:1, other:2.
And the file was actually modified.

My impression is that Eclipse just stupidly overwrites the file, otherwise there should be also some read operations, right?

That, however, doesn't help me that much, I can only see Eclipse as the process modifying the file, not much else.

Comment: While I don't have a solution to your problem I can give a word of encouragement: FabioZ, the author of PyDev is a regular of SO! :)

Comment: Good to know :) Well maybe it's not even PyDev, but it's definitively something in Eclipse, and I don't see why anything else in Eclipse would touch easy_install.pth..

Comment: Hmm, This won't fix whatever the problem is, but can you set up a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and use that for eclipse? Here's a [link to quick setup instructions](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/25/getting-started-with-virtualenv-isolated-python-environments/).

Comment: Virtualenv is great but trying to do anything with Eclipse that is not already in Eclipse is way too painful, and I would like to just get a solution for this absurdity ;)

Comment: And that's why I don't use eclipse. It's fine if everything runs through it, but otherwise.... and good luck if you want to make a simple script! I want to create myscript.py but noooo, I need a project, and a setup, and gouge my eye out with a rusty spoon if I want to edit and run something built outside eclipse

Comment: Agree with you, and luckily I never use it either, but my colleagues do so I would like to solve this... Seeing that they need more than 300k lines of Java+Python for PyDev is really scary by the way.

Comment: Just some notes... dealing with external files has been improved in the latest versions ( see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203663/110451 )... and as for the PyDev LOC, I can't really comment, as I don't keep track of it, and I'm not sure how you got to that number, but, I think tests, the internal jython and some auto-generated files such as the grammar implementations shouldn't be counted if you want to get an accurate size of the codebase...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I must say I haven't been able to reproduce this so far in PyDev... do you know if that's only happening in your machine (or some other colleague also has the same problem)?

To try to reproduce it, can you give more details on your toolchain: what's your python version and what's your setuptools version? Which packages you have installed? (my feeling is that the culprit is not really Eclipse/PyDev, but some python package that's doing that).

Just to note, PyDev simply doesn't do anything related to .pth files -- all it does is launching your python script with the PYTHONPATH setup in the environment variables for the launched process (so, it's very unlikely that PyDev is writing that file -- simply because it doesn't know anything related to .pth files).

One thing that could help in getting to the root of it: you can try making that file unwritable (you should be able to change its permissions so that you can't modify it), then, try to reproduce and see if you get some error somewhere (because if someone tries to write it, there'll be an exception because you don't get permissions to do so).

Comment: Everyone (but not always) in the office suffered this problem apparently, and for a few years already.

I also would no think that is Eclipse/PyDev, but running a command from the command line behaves well, running the same command in Eclipse doesn't.

And this only happens I configured PyDev with all the python modules available. 

If I leave that configuration empty then easy_install.pth is not touched, and that's also why I was pointing my fingerhere..

Comment: This script actually runs some python setup.py develop, so if I make it read-only nothing will work. If I could make it read-only only for eclipse and for the rest it would be useful.

I found a workaround however, just modify the sys.path on the fly merging the right things in, as a temporary solution is more than fine I think..

Comment: If modifying sys.path inside your running python script makes it work, this is a real indication that it's not PyDev who's writing that file, but your own script...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on windows, why not use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)? Turn it on, filter for your file(s), then install. It'll log who touches the file, and in what sequence. That should find your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found the fix for the real problem, but at least I found a workardound.

What I do now is to store in a text file all the egg names that should be in the sys.path at run-time.
Before doing anything else I take this list, join these paths with the correct site-packages path, and add what was missing to the sys.path.

It seems to work, but if I remove some libraries (like pyqt) even if it's they are added I still get som errors, so there is still something missing...

```
    import pkg_resources
    import sys

    from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
    from os import path
    from psi.devsonly.utils import filename_to_list


    #TODO: there appears to be an issue with QT removing the entries
    def update_sys_path():
        """Make sure that the sys path contains all the entries needed
        """
        site_packages = get_python_lib()
        req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('psi.devsonly')
        wea = pkg_resources.resource_filename(req, 'windows_easy_install.pth')
        ppack_list = filename_to_list(wea)

        for p in ppack_list:
            full_name = path.join(site_packages, p)
            # the lower() is necessary or the entries are not found
            if full_name.lower() not in sys.path:
                print("adding to the path the entry %s" % full_name)
                sys.path.insert(0, full_name)
            else:
                print("%s already present in the path" % full_name)
```

Comment: If modifying sys.path inside your running python script makes it work, this is a real indication that it's not PyDev who's writing that file, but your own script...

Comment: Ehm not sure, because I haven't actually tried to run it from Eclipse. And I don't see why it would be an indication, it could just be that Eclipse writes it when the process finishes or before it starts, my trick would work anyway.

Comment: I think that the only thing is that Eclipse gives you an environment that's a bit different and for some reason your python program doesn't behave well (the most common thing is that some environment variable is different)... Also, the fact that your program actually modifies that file (otherwise you could have it read-only) is highly suspicious... (and it seems you had only a single write when debugging -- or not?)

Comment: Not exactly, I had exactly the same problem running a script that doesn't touch it at all, and debugging the script that did modify it I saw that it could not possibly have removed those entries..

Comment: So, can you make it read-only and run the script that doesn't modify it to see if some place complains?

Comment: Alright then, I used another script which definitively doesn't touch easy-install.pth, and after 2 or 3 runs, it did it again! Now I've made the file read-only and it's not modifying it, but nothing is complaining either (I would have expected an error somewhere). This is really weird..